# App Script - How can I Speed up My setBackground() function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, setbackground

I'm struggling with my `setBackground()` function on App script. How can I speed it up? It's working but the execution is very slow.

I have written this:

```js
function changeColor(sheetName, startColorCol, sizeCellCol, totalCellCol) {

    var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName)

    for (z = startColorCol; z <= totalCellCol; z = z + sizeCellCol) {

        // As this is called onEdit() we don't want to perform the entire script every time a cell is
        // edited- only when a status cell is mofified. 
        // To ensure this, before anything else we check to see if the modified cell is actually in the status column.
        if (sSheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() == z) {
            var row = sSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
            var value = sSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
            var col = "white"; // Default background color
            var colLimit = z; // Number of columns across to affect

            switch (value) {
                case "fait":
                    col = "MediumSeaGreen";
                    break;
                case "sans réponse":
                    col = "Orange";
                    break;
                case "proposition":
                    col = "Skyblue";
                    break;
                case "Revisions Req":
                    col = "Gold";
                    break;
                case "annulé":
                    col = "LightCoral";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (row >= 3) {
                sSheet.getRange(row, z - 2, 1, sizeCellCol).setBackground(col);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I saw I might need to use batch operations but I have no idea how to make it works.

The thing is, I need to color a range of cells when the value of one is changed. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that if you just describe what you are trying to accomplish that we might be able to accomplish it with a lot less code.  Also by using the event object more efficiently than you are currently doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

- You only want to check a single cell, the cell that was edited (`var value = sSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();`). Therefore, it doesn't make sense to use a loop.

#### Solution:

- Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get the data regarding the edited cell (sheet, column index, row index, etc.), instead of using a loop and checking `getActiveCell().getColumn()` each time. This event object is passed to `onEdit` as a parameter by default (`e` in the sample below), but you should pass it to your `changeColor` function as an argument.
- Before doing anything else, check whether the edited cell is one of the edited cell is in the range you are tracking (correct sheet, row over 3, column between `startColorCol` and `totalCellCol`.
- If the edited cell is in the proper range, update the background colors.

#### Code sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // ...Some stuff...
  changeColor(e, sheetName, startColorCol,sizeCellCol, totalCellCol);
}

function changeColor(e, sheetName, startColorCol,sizeCellCol, totalCellCol) {
  const range = e.range;
  const column = range.getColumn();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const sSheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sSheet.getName() === sheetName && column >= startColorCol && column <= totalCellCol && row >= 3) {
    const value = range.getValue();
    let col = "white"; // Default background color
    switch (value) {
      case "fait":
        col = "MediumSeaGreen";
        break;
      case "sans réponse":
        col = "Orange";
        break;
      case "proposition":
        col = "Skyblue";
        break;
      case "Revisions Req":
        col = "Gold";
        break;
      case "annulé":
        col = "LightCoral";
        break;
      default:
        break;  
    }
    sSheet.getRange(row, column-2, 1, sizeCellCol).setBackground(col);
  }
}
```